# Put atualizar objeto

Tags: java, android

O que há de errado com o meu put? Era pra fazer a atualização de objetos no meu banco,mas não funciona corretamente,não retorna nenhum erro,apenas não atualiza.

```
public String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            String result = "";


            try {


                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_users");

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                String json = "";



                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestProperty("X-DreamFactory-Api-Key", "36fda24fe5588fa4285ac6c6c2fdfbdb6b6bc9834699774c9bf777f706d05a88");
                conn.setRequestProperty("X-DreamFactory-Session-Token", "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.XXXXXXXXXX.jfGbU3yjIPPfAQWTyYVQJCfEapYFnHPCYkL4T-arD4M");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXX");
                conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                json = jsonObject.toString();


                jsonObject.put("id_user", id);
                jsonObject.put("tx_name", nome);
                jsonObject.put("tx_nickname", nickname );
                jsonObject.put("nu_cellphone", numcel );
                jsonObject.put("password", password );
                jsonObject.put("tx_email", email );
                Log.e("resource", jsonObject.toString());



                JSONObject resource = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                array.put(json);
                resource.put("resource", array);

                System.out.println(resource.toString());


                conn.connect();

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(resource.toString());

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();


                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println("Chegou até aqui");


                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                   System.out.println("Funcionou");


                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line = "";


                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }
```

> Retorno dos systems...
>   07-25 14:16:32.248 21317-22373/com.example.thiago.myapplication E/resource: {"id_user":"2","tx_name":"Teste","tx_nickname":"Teste","nu_cellphone":"(11)99838-9998","password":"12345","tx_email":"tvdc1gg@gmail.com"}
>   07-25 14:16:32.258 21317-22373/com.example.thiago.myapplication I/System.out: {"resource":["{}"]}

Comment: Você consegue ver a resposta que retorna do servidor? Está dando exceção?

Comment: Coloquei o retorno dos systems

Comment: O servidor foi configurado para suportar o método `PUT` ?